# std::make_unsigned mangling/linking error

Tags: c++, template-specialization, type-traits

I am trying to do something like this

```
template<class T>
void foo(typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type x)
    {
    //do a lot with x (do not want to repeat for signed vs unsigned)
    }

template<class T>
void foo(T x)
    {
    if(x < 0)
        {x=-x;}
    foo<typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type>
        (static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type >(x));
    }
```

When I try to use forced explicit instanciation (extern templates), i get the following demangled output from nm:

```
void foo<unsigned long long>(std::make_unsigned<unsigned long long>::type)
```

Now, why does not std::make_unsigned::type emit the same type as if I wrote unsigned T explicity? Instead I get undefined references.

Answer (score 0):

I think explicit initialization/secialization of member is not allowed.
But I could not find exact c++ refrence.